# Given the conic section $Ax^2+2Bxy+Cy^2=1$ where $A>0$ and $B^2<AC$.

Tags: geometry

Given the conic section $Ax^2+2Bxy+Cy^2=1$ where $A>0$ and $B^2<AC$. Let $m$ and $M$ denote the distances from the origin to the nearest and furthest points of the conic. Show that $$M^2=\dfrac{A+C+\sqrt{(A-C)^2+4B^2}}{2(AC-B^2)}$$

Here I tried to use Lagrange's method of undetermined multipliers. But it is getting complicated. Is there any other way

Comment: Lagrange multipliers should be the way to go here.

Comment: But the calculation is getting cubersome. So may be there is another way

Comment: You have some options: use computers, or do elimination by hand.  Given the shape of the answer, you know you're going to have to crank some quadratic formulae sooner or later.  

I considered an interesting option of applying a rotation to eliminate the $ B $, but it turns out that figuring out the rotation angle is even more tedious than the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $r = [x, y]^T$, then the given equation can be written as

$ r^T Q r = 1 $

where $Q = \begin{bmatrix} A && B \\ B && C \end{bmatrix} $

Diagonalize $Q$, by introducing $ \theta = \frac{1}{2} \tan^{-1} \dfrac{2 B}{A - C} $

Now, $Q$ can be written as $Q = R D R^T$, where

$D_{11} = A \cos^2 \theta + C \sin^2 \theta + 2 B \sin \theta \cos \theta $

$D_{22} = A \sin^2 \theta + C \cos^2 \theta - 2 B \sin \theta \cos \theta $

Using standard trigonometric identities, this becomes

$D_{11} = \frac{1}{2}(A + C) + \frac{1}{2}(A - C) \cos(2 \theta) + B \sin(2 \theta) $

$D_{22} = \frac{1}{2}(A + C) - \frac{1}{2}(A - C) \cos(2 \theta) - B \sin(2 \theta) $

Now, since $tan(2 \theta) = \dfrac{2 B}{A - C} $ , then

$ \cos(2 \theta) = \dfrac{ A - C }{ \sqrt{ 4 B^2 + (A - C)^2 }} $

$ \sin(2 \theta) = \dfrac{ 2 B } { \sqrt{4 B^2 + (A - C)^2 }} $

Therefore,

$ D_{11} = \frac{1}{2} (A + C) + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{ (A - C)^2 + 4 B^2} $

$ D_{22} = \frac{1}{2} (A + C) - \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{ (A - C)^2 + 4 B^2 } $

Therefore, the rotated ellipse have a semi-major axis of $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{D_{22}}}$ and a semi-minor axis of $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{D_{11}}} $

Now, we have

$ \dfrac{1}{D_{11}} = \dfrac{2}{ A + C + \sqrt{(A - C)^2 + 4 B^2 } } = \dfrac{2 ( A + C - \sqrt{(A - C)^2 + 4 B^2 }) }{ 4 (AC -  B^2) } $

So that,

$ \dfrac{1}{D_{11}} = \dfrac{ A + C -  \sqrt{(A - C)^2 + 4 B^2 }}{2( A C - B^2)} $

Similarly,

$ \dfrac{1}{D_{22}} = \dfrac{ A + C + \sqrt{ (A - C)^2 + 4 B^2 }}{ 2 (AC - B^2)} $

Answer (score 1):

HINT.- You can use the theory on the general equation of the conics.
$$Ax^2+2Bxy+Cy^2+2Dx+2Ey+F=0$$ Since $B^2\lt AC$ we have ellipses.

►The center is given by $f'_x=f'_y=0$ so the center is the origine $(0,0)$.

►If $m$ and $m'$ are the slopes of two conjugate diameters in the ellipse we have$$Cmm'+B(m+m')+A=0$$ from which you have the slopes of the two axis of the ellipses which are conjugate and perpendicular $$Bm^2+(A-C)m-B=0$$ Consequently the axis have equations
$$y=\frac{A-C+\sqrt{(A-C)^2+4B^2}}{2B}\space x\\y=\frac{A-C-\sqrt{(A-C)^2+4B^2}}{2B}\space x$$

►You can finish now with the intersection of two axis with the ellipse  $Ax^2+2Bxy+Cy^2-1=0$ (the axis being, of course, your $M$ and $m$).

Comment: I surely wanted mean semi-major and semi-minor axes instead of axes when refering to $M$ and $m$ at the end of my answer. ( Weak English....)

Comment: There exists a connection with eigenvalues $$\lambda_1,\lambda_2=\dfrac{A+C\pm\sqrt{(A-C)^2+4B^2}}{2}$$